# How to add a correlation value in your plot ( ggplot )

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, correlation

Hello people me again,

**[Story/Issue]**
I have an issue with my shiny app bellow. I'm trying to insert a spearman, kendall or pearson correlation coefficient in my scatterplot. ***This is done @ code line nr. 160.*** I do not nessesarily get an error out of it but i do get some weird text in the left top of my plot as seen in the image.

**[Question]** Could anyone help me / point me in the right direction as to how I can propperly display the correlation coefficient on the left top of my plot.  If possible please do tell me how to specify the location of where the text would be projected( i assume this is documented in the ?function if this is the case ill find it out ).

I've tried a number of different things such as "stat_cor, cor.test ( and then insert ) , geom_cor and a few more" But they ether dont work because they take an entire DF > specific x,y values or give me the same italic error as seen in the picture.

If the code does not work for you, or you need/want me to edit something because this question is not constructed correctly do please tell me as I'm still quite wet behind the ears in both R and stackoverflow.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Screenshot of the scatterplot *note left top]

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
# http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#
if(!require(tidyverse)){
    install.packages("tidyverse")
    library(tidyverse)
}

if(!require(shiny)){
    install.packages("shiny")
    library(shiny)
}

if(!require(shinydashboard)){
    install.packages("shinydashboard")
    library(shinydashboard)
}

if(!require(DT)){
    install.packages("DT")
    library(DT)
}

library(cbsodataR)
library(rgdal)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(plotly)
library(ggpubr)

setwd("D:/")

import_producentenvertrouwen <- cbs_get_data(id = "81234ned")
import_consumentenvertrouwen <- cbs_get_data(id = "83693NED")
import_cpi <- cbs_get_data(id = "71905ned")
import_regionale_kenmerken <- cbs_get_data(id = "83978NED")

#download.file("http://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/wijkenbuurten2019/extract/wijkenbuurten2019.zip", destfile = "wijken_buurten.zip")
#unzip(zipfile = "wijken_buurten.zip", files = "WijkBuurtkaart_2019_v1.gpkg")
#import_gemeente <- readOGR("WijkBuurtkaart_2019_v1.gpkg")

cpi_df <- import_cpi %>%
    transmute("Jaar" = as.character(gsub(Perioden, pattern = "JJ00", replacement = "")),
              "CPI" = as.numeric(CPI_1),
              "CPI_cum" = as.numeric(JaarmutatieCPI_2))

labels <- attributes(x = import_producentenvertrouwen$BedrijfstakkenBranchesSBI2008)$labels
branches <- names(labels)
branches_df <- data.frame(labels, branches)

producentenvertrouwen_df <- cbind(import_producentenvertrouwen,
                                  as.data.frame(str_split_fixed(import_producentenvertrouwen$Perioden, pattern = "MM", n = 2))) %>%
    left_join(branches_df, by = c("BedrijfstakkenBranchesSBI2008" = "labels")) %>%
    transmute("Branches" = branches,
              "Jaar" = as.numeric(V1),
              "Maand" = as.numeric(V2),
              "Producentenvertrouwen" = as.numeric(Producentenvertrouwen_1))

consumentenvertrouwen_df <- cbind(import_consumentenvertrouwen,
                                  as.data.frame(str_split_fixed(import_consumentenvertrouwen$Perioden, pattern = "MM", n = 2))) %>%
    transmute("Jaar" = as.numeric(V1),
              "Maand" = as.numeric(V2),
              "Consumentenvertrouwen" = as.numeric(Consumentenvertrouwen_1))

full_df <- right_join(producentenvertrouwen_df, consumentenvertrouwen_df)

ggplot(full_df) +
    geom_point(aes(y = Producentenvertrouwen, x = Consumentenvertrouwen)) +
    facet_wrap(~Branches)

maanden <- as.factor(c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"))

#filtered_df <- full_df

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- dashboardPage(
    skin = "black",
    dashboardHeader(
        title = "Data-dashboard"
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
            menuItem("TBD", tabName = "TBD", icon = icon("th"))
        )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            # First tab content
            tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
                    h2("Dashboard"),
                    fluidRow(
                        box(
                            title = "Branches",
                            checkboxGroupInput("branche", "Selecteer branche", choices = branches, selected = branches),
                            actionButton("selectall","Selecteer alle branches"),
                            actionButton("unselectall","Selecteer slechts \u00E9\u00E9n branche")
                        ),
                        box(
                            title = "Periode",
                            sliderInput("jaar", "Selecteer periode (jaren)", min = min(full_df$Jaar), max = max(full_df$Jaar), value = c("1986", "2020")),
                            sliderInput("maand", "Selecteer periode (maanden)", min = min(full_df$Maand), max = max(full_df$Maand), value = c("1", "12"))
                        )),
                    fluidRow(
                        box(
                            title = "Visuals",
                            plotlyOutput("scatterplot"),
                            width = 12
                            
                        )
                    )
            ),
            # Second tab content
            tabItem(tabName = "TBD",
                    h2("TBD"),
                    fluidRow(
                        DTOutput("datatable")
                    ),
                    h2("TBD"),
                    fluidRow(
                        # selectInput("select", label = "Kies ...", choices = files/variables, selected = NULL),
                        # DTOutput("datatable")
                    )
            )
        )
    )
    
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    plot_filtered <- function(){
        req(input$jaar, input$maand, input$branche)
        min_jaar <- min(input$jaar)
        max_jaar <- max(input$jaar)
        min_maand <- min(input$maand)
        max_maand <- max(input$maand)
        full_df %>%
            filter(Jaar >= min_jaar & Jaar <= max_jaar) %>%
            filter(Maand >= min_maand & Maand <= max_maand) %>%
            filter(Branches == input$branche) %>%
            ggplot() +
            geom_point(aes(x=Producentenvertrouwen, y=Consumentenvertrouwen))+
            geom_smooth(aes(x=Producentenvertrouwen, y=Consumentenvertrouwen),method='lm',se=F,color="red")+
            geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(Producentenvertrouwen)))+
            geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(Consumentenvertrouwen)))+
            ggtitle("Consumenten vergeleken met producentenvertrouwen per branch")+
            theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
            ylim(-75,50)+
            xlim(-35,15)+
            stat_cor(aes(x=Producentenvertrouwen, y=Consumentenvertrouwen),method="spearman")+
            labs(caption = "Bron: CBS")
    }
    output$scatterplot <- plotly::renderPlotly({plot_filtered()})
    output$datatable <- DT::renderDataTable(
        datatable( data = filtered_df,
                   editable = TRUE,
                   rownames = FALSE
                   , extensions = 'Buttons'
                   , options = list(
                       dom = "Blfrtip"
                       , buttons =
                           list("copy", list(
                               extend = "collection"
                               , buttons = c("csv", "excel", "pdf")
                               , text = "Download"
                           ) ) # end of buttons customization
                       # customize the length menu
                       , lengthMenu = list( c(10, 20, -1) # declare values
                                            , c(10, 20, "All") # declare titles
                       ) # end of lengthMenu customization
                       , pageLength = 10
                       
                   ) # end of options
        ) #%>% formatCurrency(2:7, "\u20AC"), # end of datatables
    )
    observe({
        req(input$select)
        s_select <- get(input$select)
    })
    observe({
        input$selectall
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, 'branche', 'Selecteer branche', choices = branches, selected = branches)
    })
    observe({
        input$unselectall
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, 'branche', 'Selecteer branche', choices = branches, selected = "C Industrie")
    })
    observe({
        if(is.null(input$branche) == T){
            updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, 'branche', 'Selecteer branche', choices = branches, selected = "C Industrie")
            showNotification("Er moet minimaal 1 branche worden geselecteerd.")
        }
    })
    observe({
        input$branche
        b_filter <- input$branche
    })
    observe({
        input$jaar
        m_filter <- input$jaar
    })
    observe({
        input$maand
        #%>%
        # filter(Maand == min(as.numeric(input$maand)) & Jaar <= max(as.numeric(input$maand))) %>%
        #ggplot() +
        #geom_point(aes(x=Consumentenvertrouwen, y=Producentenvertrouwen))+
        #geom_smooth(aes(x=Consumentenvertrouwen, y=Producentenvertrouwen),method='lm',se=F,color="red")+
        #ggtitle("Consumenten tegenover producentenvertrouwen per branch")+
        #theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
        #labs(caption = "Bron: CBS")
    })
} # end of server

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a **minimal** example? That means you have a runnable shiny app that contains only the code & ui for your specific problem. Also, it would be great if you can provide some easy accessible example data (paste the output of `dput` here or define a data.frame). Thanks!

Comment: `ggpubr ` perhaps?
https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/stat_cor.html

Comment: I this thats an issue @starja, i will do so next time as i have a tight time constraint ( for today ).  ggpubr package that Magnus Nordmo suggested seems contain the function i need to fix this ill try this out first.

Comment: ggpubr seemed to do the trick using:  ```stat_cor(aes(x=Producentenvertrouwen, y=Consumentenvertrouwen),method="pearson",cor.coef.name = c("R"),output.type = "text", p.accuracy=0.0001, label.x = -10, label.y = 30)``` Where the label.x and y are sort of used to decide where to "display" this value